Powershell - get excel object from process id
I have a running script that creates an excel object via
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$ExcelApp = $Excel.Application

Although there are some issues with FULLY disabling an XLL I load so I wanted to try a different approach that I know others use manually
If I use below, I can create new instance of excel, and get the process info (pid, main window, etc). This should help with loading my XLL and disabling on quit
$test = Start-process excel.exe /x -PassThru

However I’m not sure how to get the -comObject from this
I have seen examples like
$Excel = [RunTime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject(‘Excel.Application’) 

But I think this comes with the assumption that there can only be one excel whereas I want to ensure I get the excel ComObject only for a specific excel (for which I have the process info for)
Is there a way to tie the two together?
I’ve seen another way like
$Excel = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::GetObject($null,’Excel.Application’)

But I’m not sure how to use this as replacing $null with my $test.Id won’t work
Can anyone help?
How do I get the $Excel object from the $test process?

I suggest that you use our friend - Doug Finke's Excel module. Also, sharing Doug Finke's - Lightning talk - PowerShell Excel Module

@RanadipDutta thanks for the repo. If you’re suggesting to use his import excel library. It sounds like it is a library to work with excel without using excel? I’m not sure if my XLL that I want to load will break :p

It wont break. It will stay intact

@RanadipDutta, XLLs are special DLLs loaded by Excel, so I suspect they're not supported via the ImportExcel module - at least searching for "XLL" in the repo yields no hits.

I suggest taking the opposite route:

Every call to New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application creates a new EXCEL.exe process.

Assuming that no other process on your machine is making such calls concurrently, you can use the following to determine the EXCEL process associated with the most recent New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application call:


$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$ExcelProcess = (Get-Process Excel | Sort-Object -Descending StartTime)[0]

Note:

There are ways to use COM APIs to get the same information, but they're  much lower-level: see this blog post.

